# Pandas DataFrame - How to get first 'Name' of rows

Tags: python, pandas

I may not be asking this question right, so I think it may be better to show.

I'm accessing a row in a Pandas DataFrame using iloc[x]:

```
dataFrame.iloc[0]
```

when I print it out I get this

```
print(dataFrame.ioc[0])

x               0
y               0
z               0
a               0
b               0
c               0
d               0
Name: 2015-01-02 00:00:00, dtype: float64
```

I need to extract just the date/'Name', how do I do this?

Comment: `dataFrame.index[0]`?

Comment: @HenryEcker this returns just x for me.

Comment: What does `dataFrame` look like?

Comment: `dataFrame.iloc[0].name` to extract the name of a series or index.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny this worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To extract the index from a pandas dataframe you can simply use df.index[0]. This would allow you to get the index name of any row.

These pages were immensely helpful to me when I was starting out and I hope it's useful to you as well.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/indexing.html#

Comment: this returns just 'x' for me.

Comment: I believe you may need to clarify your question a bit more then, would you mind adding the shape of your dataframe? Do you have a multiindexed df? If you did iloc on the last command, you got back the row with all the COLUMN headers on the side, For that an easy way to get the column names would be list(df.columns)

Comment: Good to hear then.